# Problem with filling control

Tags: c#, wpf, scroll

I have problem with filling control.

In first column I have stackpanel and it has 4 controls. 
Every ScrollViewer as DataContext has TreeView, which has Height set as Auto.
When I expand nodes in my treviews it expands out of window. How can I fix it ?

```
<Grid x:Name="MainGrid">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width=".30*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width=".69*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Border CornerRadius="0" BorderBrush="#58290A"
              BorderThickness="5" Grid.Column="0" >
            <StackPanel MaxHeight="{Binding Height, ElementName=MainGrid}">

                    <ScrollViewer x:Name="ScrollViewerForOperationTree">
                    </ScrollViewer>

                <Button Content="Dodaj brakujący hotel" Click="AddHotel_Click" x:Name="btnAddHotel">
                </Button>
                <Button Content="Dodaj brakujące miasto" Click="AddCity_Click" x:Name="AddCity"></Button>
                <ScrollViewer x:Name="ScrollViewerForSimpleTree"></ScrollViewer>
            </StackPanel>
        </Border>
        <GridSplitter HorizontalAlignment="Right" 
                  VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
                  Grid.Column="1" ResizeBehavior="PreviousAndNext"
                  Width="5" Background="#FFBCBCBC"/>
        <Grid Grid.Column="2" Background="#B5CBEF" x:Name="GridObjectOperation">
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
```

Comment: Does it expand vertically or only horizontally or both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

StackPanel will give its children as much vertical space as they request, even if there isn't enough available, so the later elements will fall off the end.  Try using a Grid instead:

```
<Border CornerRadius="0" BorderBrush="#58290A"
        BorderThickness="5" Grid.Column="0" >
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="0" x:Name="ScrollViewerForOperationTree">
        </ScrollViewer>

        <Button Grid.Row="1" Content="Dodaj brakujący hotel"
                Click="AddHotel_Click" x:Name="btnAddHotel">
        </Button>
        <Button Grid.Row="2" Content="Dodaj brakujące miasto"
                Click="AddCity_Click" x:Name="AddCity"></Button>
        <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="3" x:Name="ScrollViewerForSimpleTree">
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>
</Border>
```